# How to assign several Firestore queries to an Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm staring to play with [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/) and so far so good, but I got stuck on how to retrieve documents form different queries and assign them to one Observable, so my template updates automatically.

I have a *trips* collection, which has a *passengers* collection that stores the user ID of each passenger. This ID will after be used to retrieve the profile info.

After some time of experimentation I achieved the result I wanted using a simple array and pushing the data of every document inside. Here is the code:

```
passengersIDs: AngularFirestoreCollection<{}>
passengers = []

this.passengersIDs =this.db.collection('trips').doc(this.id).collection('passengers')

this.passengersIDs.ref.get().then(data => {
     data.forEach(docu => {
     this.db.collection('profiles').doc(docu.get('passID')).ref.get().then(prof => {
        this.passengers.push(prof.data())
      })
   })
})
```

As you can see for each document, I save the data and after I iterate over it on the template.

I would like to achive the same behaivour but with `passengers = Obvserbale<Profile[]>` or something similar.

I checked both [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/) and [firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) and they were not helpfull.

Any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Using rxjs `Observable.fromPromise` you can transform your promise to Observable and use other rxjs functions to achieve your goal.

For example :

```
passenger: Observable < Profile[] >  =
Observable.fromPromise(this.db.collection('trips').doc(this.id).collection('passengers'))
.pipe(switchMap(passengers =>
        // combine the array of observables to an observable of array of results
        combineLatest(  // mapping the passengers array to an Observable<Profile> array
                        passengers.map(p =>
                            Observable.fromPromise(this.db.collection('profiles').doc(p.passID))
                            )
                    )
                )
);
```